# How to edit the content of an application.properties or application.yml file inside an existing jar on a remote Linux server

Tags: java, jar

How to edit a property file (like `application.properties`) inside of an existing jar file on a remote Linux server.

Imagine the jar is located in `/home/user/my-spring-boot.jar` and I like to change the username inside of `application.propertires` from

```
username=foo
```

to

```
username=bar
```

How to open the file and change the property?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A `.jar` file is simply a `.zip` file with a different extension, and `vim` can edit zip files and their contents directly! Simply `vim` your `.jar`, use the file navigator to find your properties file and change it. `vim` will maintain the zip with your edits.

See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Edit_Java_jar_and_other_files) for more details.

Comment: Seems very convenient, but I get a "caution: filename not matched" error after selecting a file in the navigator.

Comment: I don't think this is the right approach to "override" properties bundled in a jar.
A better way is to either pass the property using -Dusername=bar or via env variable when starting the Spring Boot app

Comment: I certainly don’t recommend the above as the best approach to managing your configuration. The above answers the specific question asked, but managing configuration properly is another (larger) topic

Answer (score 3):

Possible route could be to copy the jar into a zip file, extract, change your properties, compress to zip and rename to jar

```
cp myJar.jar myJar.zip
unzip myJar.zip
vim myProperties.properties (doing the change here)
zip allMyFiles into myJar.zip
cp myJar.zip myModifiedJar.jar
```

Comment: just what i needed :) also, to shorten, you can just do `unzip myJar.jar`

Answer (score 3):

Changing an existing JAR artifact is not a good idea. Instead, Spring Boot allows you to easily override the bundled properties with external values in several ways.

For example you can place an `application.properties` file next to the JAR with the values that you want to override. You don't even need to copy the whole properties file there, only the properties you want to change, because it still falls back to the bundled defaults.

The details are documented here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `emacs` (after having copied your file for backup):

```
$ cp /home/user/bigExecutableJar.jar /home/user/bigExecutableJar.jar.bak 
$ emacs /home/user/bigExecutableJar.jar
```

- If it is big, it will ask you if you really want to open the file.
- You can then search for the file you want to modify in the buffer listing all the files in the jar; use `C-s` to do a search if needed.
- Open the file by selecting it, and press `RET`.
- Make your changes, and save with `C-x C-s`.
- Finally close Emacs with `C-x C-c`.

Answer (score 1):

Use emacs for edit content on jar file

```
emacs jarfile
```

After opening the jar, you can browse folders and files. Search the jdbc.properties and edit it. Then save the changes with c-x c-s.

Note: Is necessary install zip and unzip

Answer (score 1):

I found Java (or maybe it was Spring Boot more specifically) to be finicky about the order of the files in the JAR (introduced circular library dependencies: "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle").  Therefore, a method of preserving the order is needed.

Unzip the original JAR `1.jar` by `unzip 1.jar` and make your changes in the generated directory tree.  Then generate a new archive `2.jar` while preserving the order of the files by using the original `1.jar` as a reference.

```
## -r = --recurse-paths
## -Z = --compression-method
zip -r -Z store 2.jar $(unzip -l 1.jar |tr -s ' ' |cut -d' ' -f5 |grep -v /$ )
zip -r -Z store 2.jar $(unzip -l 1.jar |tr -s ' ' |cut -d' ' -f5 |grep    /$ )
```

This puts the directories *after* the files, which is strange, but the only way I found to work (with respect to the circular dependency issue).  These two lines can be combined into one call to `zip`, but I separated them here for tidiness.

In order for the order preservation to work, it may be important that the new archive `2.jar` be created fresh (not already existing).

There is a Java requirement that nested JAR files be archived without further compression.  The easiest way to accomplish this was to use `-Z store` for all files written to the new archive.  This may result in the new archive being larger than the original.

You can review the internal order of the archive with something like the following (insert your favorite graphical diff utility)

```
diff <(unzip -t 1.jar) <(unzip -t 2.jar)
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack `jar` archives with the `jar xf bigExecutableJar.jar` command. If you can, I suggest to install `atool` because it offers a better command line to pack/unpack archives.

Unless you know how to handle `vi`, use `nano` as editor. Some systems also have `mc` installed which is a console based file explorer that has a built-in editor.

After changing the file, you can package the archive again using `jar cf bigExecutableJar-new.jar -C .` (or `atool --add`)

If you really want/need to use `jar`, I suggest to try the command in a new directory first because it sometimes doesn't behave as you expect. **Never use it on the original file!**

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -i "s/\(customAuthHeaderName=\).*\$/\1${customAuthHeaderName}/" configuration.properties

sed -i "s/\(logoutPage=\).*\$/\1${logoutPage}/" configuration.properties
```

Second `customAuthHeaderName` value is coming from properties file

Comment: You should provide some additional explanation